# Remove double quotes around each element in json_encoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json, quotes

I am trying to pass an array to a GoogleChart API, which will accept an array that looks like this:

```
$arr=array(['Time' , 'Value'],['08' , 100 ],['10' , 200], ['12' , 300]);
$arr=(json_encode($arr));
echo($arr);
//result
[["Time","Value"],["08",100],["10",200],["12",300]]
```

However, when I try to create the array from my database in the following manner, I wind up with double quotes around the elements I pushed into the array, and the API will not accept the array:

```
WHILE($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$time[]=$rows['Time'];
$entry[]=$rows['Entry'];
    };

 $count=count($time);

$newarr=array();
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
$x="[".$time[$i].",".$entry[$i]."]";
array_push($newarr, $x);
};

array_unshift($newarr, ["Time", "Value"]);

echo(json_encode($newarr));
//result
[["Time", "Value"], "[06:08:00,250]", "[08:08:00,230]"]
```

Is it possible to create the array without the double quotes or to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from the database, the resulting value you get is ALWAYS going to be treated like a string value.  If you want `json_encode()` to treat it like an integer, you will need to specifically cast it as an integer before doing the encoding.

You also have the additional problem that you are trying to manually build the array by concatenating  brackets to it.  It looks to me like you need to do something like this:

```
$newarr = array();
$newarr[] = array('Time', 'Value');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $newarr[] = array($row['Time'], (int) $row['Entry']);
}

echo(json_encode($newarr));
```

I also saved some steps (and memory) by just reading the SQL results directly in `$newarr`.  You can ignore this and do it the way you were before if you actually have some need for individual `$time` and `$entry` arrays later in the code.

Comment: As of php 5.3.3, json_encode also accepts a `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option that will treat numeric strings as integers.

Comment: I tried your change to the SQL and got the following: [["Time","Value"],[null,0],[null,0]]. But, by pointing out my problem of building the array manually, I reworked the code and now the API does recognize the array. I'll take another look at your SQL idea and see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @user2232681 Note that I changed the variable name to `$row` instead of `$rows` as you had, as this made more sense (you are only working with a single row at a time after all).  If you did not match up your variable names the would have been a problem.

Comment: Yes, noticed that too and fixed it and your suggestion worked like a charm!. Great help and I learned a lot today.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to push a *string* to `$newarr`, but an array:

```
$newarr[] = array($time[$i], $entry[$i]);
```